# Как расширить функционал класса std::thread? windows, c++

Tags: c++, windows, многопоточность, классы

Нужно при создании экземпляра класса передать функцию с параметрами конструктору родительского класса. мой код:

```
class Thread : public std::thread 
{
private:
public:
    std::atomic<bool> isDone = false;
    Thread() = delete;
    Thread(???) : std::thread(???)
    {
        this->detach();
    };
    ~Thread();
};
```

И второй вопрос, как определить, что поток завершил работу и выставить `true` в `std::atomic<bool>`?

Comment: ¿И в чем же проблема передать те параметры, которые передавали бы в `::std::thread` при обычном запуске? Поток завершает работу, когда `::std::thread::joinable` возвращает `true`, это происходит после того, как метод `::std::thread::join` вернулся. Вызов `detach` является ошибкой.

Comment: @user7860670
в том и вопрос, что именно нужно написать место ??? если я хочу передать любую функцию с любым количеством аргументов из конструктора дочернего класса конструктору родительского класса? и если функция, которая будет исполнена в отдельном потоке, может возвращать значение, где/как его прочитать?

Comment: @user7860670 `int printHello() {std::cout<<"hello\n; return 0;}` `std::thread t(printHello); while (!t.joinable()){std::cout << "w8 4 end\n"; }` такой код никогда не выйдет из цикла, значит, joinable() не то, что нужно, либо я не так понял. join блокирует родительский поток, а я бы хотел не блокируя родительский поток проверять, закончил ли работу дочерний поток

Comment: Если хотите передавать любые параметры, то делайте шаблонный конструктор с форвардингом аргументов. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452512/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5

Comment: Стандартного неблокирующего метода проверки нет. Как вариант, можно выставлять атомарный флажок при выходе из точки входа потока. Но реально завершится он в любом случае после возврата `join`

Comment: @user7860670 насколько я понял, join() не убивает поток, а только проверяет, закончена ли работа предыдущей функции. как снова передать в уже созданный поток функцию на исполнение? код: `std::thread t(printThreadNumber);  t.join(); t = std::thread(printThreadNumber); t.join();` возвращает номер другого потока. или я сделал правильно, но номер потока меняется после join()?

Comment: Задавайте по одному вопросу в вопросе.

Comment: @user7860670 это одна цельная проблема, научиться создавать потоки, передавать им задачи, получать результаты, передавать задачи снова в уже созданные потоки. новый вопрос:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452882/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-stdthread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, самый первый вопрос вроде бы можно решить так:

```
class Thread: public thread
{
public:
    template<class Fn, class... Args>
    Thread(Fn&& Fx, Args&&... Ax):
    thread(forward<Fn>(Fx), forward<Args>(Ax)...)
    {

    }
};
```

Для отслеживания... Как вариант на коленке: еще один поток следит за основным (через `join()`) и выставляет флаг, когда первый завершен. Что-то вроде

```
class Thread
{

public:
    template<class Fn, class... Args>
    Thread(Fn&& Fx, Args&&... Ax)
    :run(forward<Fn>(Fx), forward<Args>(Ax)...)
    ,check([this](){ this->run.join(); this->isDone = true; })
    {
    }
    ~Thread(){ check.join(); }
private:
    thread run, check;
public:
    atomic<bool> isDone = false;
};
```

См. https://ideone.com/PnWJGd

Comment: Несколько лет назад копал в сторону сокетов, там была функция блокирующая поток, пока она читает. и она сама не завершалась, если ничего не поступает, просто продолжала ждать. выход был в том, чтобы бесконечный цикл проверял через select, есть ли что-то прочитать или нет, но не читал. и только потом запускалась функция на чтение данных. здесь я вижу join(), который блокирует поток, но заранее неизвестно, закончилась та функция в другом потоке или нет. есть ли тут подобное решение или только через флаги типа std::atomic<bool> можно решить вопрос?

Comment: Боюсь дать уверенный ответ, что вроде как нет; может, кто-то что-то и придумает...