# Как правильно повторно использовать экземпляр класса std::thread?

Tags: c++, windows, многопоточность

Насколько я понял, join() не уничтожает поток, а лишь ждёт завершение его главной функции. Как использовать поток снова без затрат на его создание? примерный код:

```
int myfunc()
{
std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
return 0;
}
std::thread t;
max = 5;
for (int i=0; i!=max;++i)
{
t = std::thread(myfunc);
t.join();
}
```

показывает, что id каждый раз другой. поток каждый раз снова создается или был передан только указатель на функцию?

Comment: Видимо вы изобретаете инфраструктуру, аналогичную https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async

Comment: @user7860670 С клавиатуры сняли :) — хотел написать "а не хотите посмотреть на `async`?"... Правда, мне кажется, что речь скорее идет о создании пула потоков. По вопросу: вот такое присваивание `t = std::thread(myfunc);` автоматически уничтожает предыдущий объект, так что его больше нет, теперь это новый объект.